Printing on multiple page
in the below code next page can not be added.whats wrong in it
I have enabled e.hasmorepage to true when number of lines reached to 10.But printing on next page can not be started
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage


        Dim l, t, right, b As Integer
        Dim companyName As String = "G.M.Agencies"
        l = e.MarginBounds.Left
        t = e.MarginBounds.Top
        right = e.MarginBounds.Right
        b = e.MarginBounds.Bottom
        Dim bor As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
        Dim brushee As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        Dim nameFont As New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim nameFont2 As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim StringAlignment As New StringFormat()
        StringAlignment.Alignment = Drawing.StringAlignment.Far
        Dim formatednumber As String

        Dim r As New Rectangle(l - 50, t - 50, right - 10, b - 10)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(bor, r)

        'Draw line below the seller name
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, l - 50, t + 100, right + 40, t + 100)

        'draw vertical line for seller and buyer
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 350, t - 50, (right - 350), t + 100)

        'draw the line below item description and below the header text
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, l - 50, t + 150, right + 40, t + 150)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, l - 50, b - 150, right + 40, b - 150)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, l - 50, b - 250, right + 40, b - 250)

        'Draw the vertical line in item details table
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, l + 10, t + 100, l + 10, b - 250)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 370, t + 100, right - 370, b - 150)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 273, t + 100, right - 273, b - 250)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 205, t + 100, right - 205, b - 250)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 125, t + 100, right - 125, b - 250)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(bor, right - 70, t + 100, right - 70, b - 150)

        'Printing Company and invoice details
        e.Graphics.DrawString(companyName, nameFont, Brushes.Black, l - 40, t - 40)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Dharapuram", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, l - 40, t)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Invoice No", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, l - 40, t + 20)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, l - 40, t + 40)

        'Printing header text
        e.Graphics.DrawString("S.No", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, l - 40, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Description", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, l + 40, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("HSN Code", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 360, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("GST %", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 270, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Rate", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 200, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 120, t + 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 60, t + 120)


        'grand total
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 170, b - 180, StringAlignment)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total CGST", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 170, b - 200, StringAlignment)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total SGST", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 170, b - 220, StringAlignment)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total  IGST", nameFont2, Brushes.Black, right - 170, b - 240, StringAlignment)

      


        'printing item details
        Dim dataGridViewRows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dg_sales_entry.Rows
        Dim dataGridViewColumns As DataGridViewColumnCollection = dg_sales_entry.Columns
        Dim numRows As Integer = dataGridViewRows.Count
        Dim numCols As Integer = dataGridViewColumns.Count
        Dim startX As Integer = l - 40
        Dim startY As Integer = t + 170
        Dim cellPadding As Integer = 10
        Dim currentY As Integer = startY

        ' For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dataGridViewColumns
        '  e.Graphics.DrawString(column.HeaderText, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, startX, currentY)
        'startX += column.Width + cellPadding
        '  Next

        'currentY += dg_sales_entry.Rows(0).Height

        Dim grand_total As Double
        Dim cgst As Double
        Dim sgst As Double
        Dim igst As Double
        Dim page_number As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        ' Dim ii As Integer = 0

        For i = ii To numRows - 1


            'calculating grand total,cgst,igst

            grand_total = grand_total + dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
            cgst = cgst + dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value
            sgst = sgst + dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value
            igst = igst + dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value




            Dim formated_number As String = (Double.Parse(dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value)).ToString("F2")
            Dim formatednuber2 As String = formated_number.PadLeft(25 - formated_number.ToString.Length)
            Dim rate As String = (Double.Parse(dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)).ToString("F2")
            Dim rate2 As String = rate.PadLeft(10 - rate.Length)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(i + 1, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, l - 40, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridViewRows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString(), dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, l + 40, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridViewRows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString(), dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 360, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridViewRows(i).Cells(12).Value.ToString(), dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 270, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rate2, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 200, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridViewRows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString(), dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 120, currentY)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(formatednuber2, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 60, currentY)




            'currentX += dataGridViewColumns(j).Width + cellPadding
            currentY += dg_sales_entry.Rows(i).Height
            page_number += 1
            ii += 1

            If page_number > 10 And page_number < 12 Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                Exit For
            End If



        Next





        'Printing total and taxes
        e.Graphics.DrawString(grand_total, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Red, right - 60, b - 180)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(sgst, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 60, b - 220)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(cgst, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 60, b - 200)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(igst, dg_sales_entry.Font, Brushes.Black, right - 60, b - 240)
        e.HasMorePages = False

    End Sub


This is a perfect example of why you ALWAYS need to debug your code before posting a question. The problem would have been obvious if you had done that. You say:

I have enabled e.hasmorepage to true when number of lines reached to 10

That is true but, if you had actually debugged the code, you'd have noticed that the last line of code that gets executed in that event handler is this:
e.HasMorePages = False

It doesn't matter if you set it to True if you set it back to False again before the method completes.
It's hard to say for sure either way but I suspect that you are under the impression that multiple pages should be printed by that loop. That's not the case. That's not how the PrintPage event handler works. Each time that event is raised, you print ONE page. If you want to print multiple pages, the event needs to be raised multiple times. That's what e.HasMorePages is for. If that is True when the method completes, the event will be raised again and you can print another page. That keeps happening until e.HasMorePages is False when the method completes.
It's up to you to keep track of what page is being printed and what data that requires. Because you're persisting values - the page number at least, but possibly more - between method calls, you should be using one or more variables declared outside the PrintPage event handler. In VB, you can possibly use Static variables instead. You should also note that the BeginPrint and EndPrint events are raised once each for each print run, regardless of how many times PrintPage is raised. You can use them for setup and cleanup code.
I suggest that you read the documentation for the PrintPage event. It includes a link to an example of printing multiple pages, so you can build on that. If you want to ask a specific question about tracking pages or the like, you should ask a new question and include only the information specific to that issue. In future, make sure that you ALWAYS read the relevant documentation when you have an issue, BEFORE posting questions that it probably answers.
